# Writing my own syntatic sugar function to work with Await.result

Tags: scala

How could I transform this:

```
Await.result(purchase, 5 seconds)
```

To be able to write the same statement in the following way:

```
purchase.await(5 seconds)
```

Just trying to learn how to rewrite some of my code by writing my own custom dsl.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own **implicit class**:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Awaitable}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object syntax {
  object await {
    implicit class AwaitableOps[T](private val awaitable: Awaitable[T]) extends AnyVal {
      @inline
      final def await(atMost: Duration): T =
        Await.result(awaitable, atMost)
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
import syntax.await._
purchase.await(5.seconds) // Note the dot. The postFix operator syntax is discouraged.
```

Answer (score 3):

In Scala 3 you might write [extension method](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html) like so

```
def [T](f: Future[T]).await(atMost: Duration) = Await.result(f, atMost)
```

[scastie example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MlmxFbdlTiWCPW8hv0neQw)