# What scala language feature is this using? It seems to extract values from a JsObject and cast it?

Tags: scala

I'm just reading some scala source code to learn from, and I came accorss this:

How is `o str "t"` working here?
It seems to be extracting the "t" key from the JsObject and casting it to a string?

```
  Try(Json parse str) map {
        case o: JsObject =>
          o str "t" flatMap {
            case "p" => Some(Ping(o int "l"))
```

There are similar patters like:

```
case "opening" =>
              for {
                d    <- o obj "d"
                path <- d str "path"
                fen  <- d str "fen"
                variant = dataVariant(d)
              } yield Opening(variant, Path(path), FEN(fen))
```

Not sure what `o obj "d"` is doing?  Or more importantly, how it is doing this?

I can't seem to find any scalaz references or package level implicits that would allow this?

Reference: https://github.com/ornicar/lila-ws/blob/master/src/main/scala/ipc/ClientOut.scala#L112

Comment: `o foo x` is the same as `o.foo(x)` it is just calling a method, nothing more. Being honest, most people would find that code not idiomatic, that trick is usually reserved for operators like `1 + 2` or very standard methods like `list map { x => x  + 1 }`.

Comment: but ```o.str("t")``` doesn't work.  confused...?

Comment: What? witchcraft! Not really, that doesn't make sense, which error do you get?

Comment: ``` value str is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsObject``` is the error I get, but it compiles fine in the project I linked above.

Comment: Maybe it is added as an **extension method**, do you get that error in the same file where `o str "t"` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `o obj "d"` uses combination of [extension method via implicit conversion](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/) and [infix notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-1-infix-notation). Desugared it translates to

```
augment(o).str("t")
```

where [`augment`](https://github.com/ornicar/lila-ws/blob/b40c9ba9469c4fdff92e922c145f81830d93b580/src/main/scala/util/LilaJsObject.scala#L33) is defined by

```
final class LilaJsObject(private val js: JsObject) extends AnyVal {

  def str(key: String): Option[String] =
    (js \ key).asOpt[String]

  ...
}

object LilaJsObject {

  implicit def augment(o: JsObject) = new LilaJsObject(o)
}
```

This low level implementation of extension method could be simplified using *implicit classes*

```
implicit final class LilaJsObject(private val js: JsObject) extends AnyVal {
  def str(key: String): Option[String] =
    (js \ key).asOpt[String]
}
```

In Scala 3 [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456236/5205022) syntax becomes even simpler.

Try seeing how infix punctuation-free notation desugars by executing

```
scala -Xprint:parser -e '"Hello" charAt 2'
```

which should display `"Hello".charAt(2)`. Infix notation can lead to beautiful [DSL](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3087.html#comment-11363), for example,

```
object repeat {
  def it(n: Int) = new {
    def times[A](f: => A): Unit = (1 to n).foreach(_ => f)
  }
}
```

can express in almost human language

```
repeat it 5 times { println("hello") }
```